# Simple AngularJS Click-To-Animate "Argument 'AppCtrl' is not a function, got undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to write a very basic AngularJS app that performs an animation when a button is clicked, I can't figure out why it's not working I copied a tutorial in verbatim and can't figure out why the tutorial is wrong.

**UPDATE:** I got it working, for some reason there was another ng-app inside the html tag. You can copy the code below and load it up immediately and play around with animations if you copy everything:

Here's what animatetest.html looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Top Animation</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">

    <button id="my-button" class="btn-primary" ng-click="app.fadeIt()">Click to fade</button>
    <div id="my-badge" class="badge" hide-me="app.isHidden">Fade me</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.11.6/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's what test.js looks like:

var app = angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"]);

```
app.controller("AppCtrl", function () {
  this.isHidden = false;
  this.fadeIt = function () {
    this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
  }
});

app.directive("hideMe", function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.hideMe, function (newVal) {
      if (newVal) {
        TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity: 0});
      }
    })
  }
});
```

**UPDATE 2:** Here's a sample plunker that's 10x better than the example above since it removes the need for a third party TweenMax library to do the actual animation:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WU6y8ka0udXHzZvCeZPc

Comment: You did a good job explaining your problem and presenting the code, to take it one step further it would be great if you worked within plnkr.co while learning the ropes so you can share live samples that others can edit to get you to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Well yes... but the biggest problem is you're following a tutorial that is buggy. You have `ng-app` twice... once nested. It's got jquery selectors inside an angular function on an element... and jquery isn't even loaded.

And you're using a fairly old version of bootstrap (relatively speaking).

There are 2 better options than using jquery in your tween function... First, you could specify exactly which element by passing it as a parameter in your `fadeIt` function, or better yet, handle this via a custom directive using isolate scope.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Top Animation</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl as testApp">

      <div id="my-button" class="btn btn-primary" click-fade>Fade me</div>



    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

test.js:

```
angular.module("app",['ngAnimate'])

.directive('clickFade',function(){

    return function(scope, element) {
            element.bind("click", function() {
                TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity: 0});
            })
        }

})
```

Notice how I removed the use of jQuery, and also your function for clicking/fading was on the wrong element.

Comment: ah true didn't notice the jQuery... I also see TweenMax which needs it's own lib

Comment: it's likely you're getting `AppCtrl is not defined` because `$` is not defined.

Comment: ah nice solution I also posted one with just using built in directives http://plnkr.co/edit/WU6y8ka0udXHzZvCeZPc

Comment: Awesome thanks shaunhusain! that's a perfect example.

Comment: No problem I actually just re-saved it and removed the ngAnimate dependency just to make it clear this isn't necessary for this case.  If you include ng-animate certain directives (ng-view, ng-show/hide, etc.) will trigger a sequence of classes to be added and removed that you can use to get finer grained control of an animation if need be. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate